# jquery title selector error in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, selector

why is it giving error in ie, when i try to change the title.

```
$('title').text('new title');
or
$('title').html('new title');
```

works fine in other browsers.

btw i just want to mention, when i try to get the value of title using following code, it works fine.

```
alert($('title'));
```

anyone has any idea on why its doing this? its soo annoying to fix bugs for ie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the `document.title` property to an ordinary string.

Comment: can you show example on how to change the title with a string?

Comment: stupid stackoverflow telling me "you can accept an answer in 7 minutes"  anyway thank you soo much, this worked.. :)  dunno why they dont fix this in jquery..

Comment: It looks like an IE bug.  `$('title')` is useless